# Separate data source with Multi-Tenancy

Tags: spring-boot, multi-tenant

Compile not error but I can't get value `instance` from `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver`.because I created two class and implement from `MultiTenantConnectionProvider`.

Example

```
@Component
public class Read implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {
   ....
}
```

```java
 properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
 properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, Read.class);
 properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.class);
```

```
@Component
public class Write implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {
   ....
}
```

```java
 properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
 properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, Write.class);
 properties.put(Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.class);
```

**Noted** I really need separate provider because I have data source for Read Only and Write only.

**Question**
How to solve this problem ?
How to seperate datasource in Multi-Tenancy ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to connect to two different data sources ?'

Comment: my question I just want to seperate datasource in Multi-Tenancy. because Multi-Tenancy it have class provider for connection to database. my problem I can't connect it.